# Mostrar array de JavaScript tal cual está compuesto

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un **array** como este:

```
var array = ["ejemplo.com","otrositio.com","etcetera.net"];
```

Y quiero mostrarlo en un `textarea` tal cual es (con los corchetes, comas y comillas), es decir, así:

```
["ejemplo.com","otrositio.com","etcetera.net"]
```

Por si ayuda, lo hago con el fin de elaborar un código personalizado que tienen que colocar los usuarios, y en ese código debe haber un array, que es este.

Sé como añadirlo al textarea, por el momento, solo necesito que se almacene en una variable normal como un string cualquiera.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basta con usar [`JSON.stringify( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify), que está precisamente para eso: Convertir un `Array` o un `Object` en una cadena de texto:

```js
var array = ["ejemplo.com", "otrositio.com", "etcetera.net"];
var texto = JSON.stringify(array);

console.log(texto);
console.log(typeof(texto));
```

> ```
> '["ejemplo.com","otrositio.com","etcetera.net"]'
> "string"
> ```

La cadena resultante, adicionalmente, es un JSON válido, que puede ser enviado o almacenado tal cual.

Answer (score 5):

Otra opción a la aportada por @Trauma es usar los [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) junto al método [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join):

```js
let array = ["ejemplo.com", "otrositio.com", "etcetera.net"];
var texto = `["${array.join('","')}"]`;
console.log(texto, typeof(texto));
```

**Edito**: la de @Trauma es mejor opción, quede claro.

Comment: ¿Qué ventaja tendría hacerlo así?

Comment: Ventaja para este problema en concreto entiendo que ninguna. Voy a editar para dejar claro que es mejor alternativa la de @Trauma (para que no lleve a confusión)

Comment: +1 Gran opción: mas genérica, y permite algún tratamiento adicional en caso de necesitarlo :-)