# Responder en JSON

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

¿Se puede responder lo siguiente en formato JSON en pantalla ?Necesito mostrar lo que me sale en consola en pantalla en formato JSON, se puede?

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const phantom = require('phantom');

app.get( '/', function ( req, res ) {
    res.send( 'Saludos desde express' );
} );

 
(async function() {
  const instance = await phantom.create();
  const page = await instance.createPage();
  await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
    console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
  });
 
  var array = ["https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators"];
  var texto = JSON.stringify(array);
  
  console.log(texto);
  console.log(typeof(texto)); 
  await instance.exit();
})();

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("El servidor está inicializado en el puerto 4000");
   });
```

Comment: Revisate este enlace [express-json-views](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-json-views) y este otro [json-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-viewer).

Answer (score 0):

Han respondido a una pregunta similar hace no mucho. Te dejo el [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245980/mostrar-array-de-javascript-tal-cual-est%C3%A1-compuesto) para que le votes si te soluciona el problema. La respuesta sería utilizar  `JSON.stringify( )`, el cual te crea una cadena de texto con formato JSON.

Comment: Mira arriba, lo modifique, pero solo me sale `https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators` y `string`, sabes como lo puedo mostrar en pantalla y no en consola?

Comment: para mostrarlo por pantalla podrías hacerlo con `alert(texto)`. O si quieres que aparezca en la página, crea un div y haz `getelementbyid("idDelDiv").innerhtml=texto`.  De todas formas, lo que le estas pasando al stringify(), es un único String, por lo que `https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators` y `string` es el formato correcto de JSON para la variable array.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es colocar entre corchetes la URL.

Prueba esto:

```js
var array = "https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators";
var texto = JSON.stringify(array); 
console.log(texto);
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu error es la interpretación de lo que es JSON. JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) es un formato ligero de intercambio de datos que se ha convertido en un estandar por los simple de interpretar y leer.  Los objetos se componen de una coleccion de pares, que se denominan clave/valor.

Ejemplo1.

`{"nombre":"Juan", "apellido":"Burgos"}`

Los tipo datos que mas se utilizan en esta notación son: String, Number, Array, Object

Ejemplo2:

```
{"string":"Texo Libre", "number": 12344, "array":[1,3,5], "objeto":{"valor":1}}
```